# Collection for ThreadIds

Tags: java

I am looking for a thread-safe collection of to store ThreadIDs (long) in Java. What is the best option? I need to preserve the order of addition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any list and wrap it with a `Synchronized Implementation`.

**Example:**

```
List<Type> list =
    Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Type>());
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use Synchronized as I'm doing a lock implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need a list (this is not obvious from your post). [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) is one option. This offers best performance if it is mostly read, and writes are fairly rare.